# Assign Value if checked checkedbox to input fields which is next to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to assign value if  checked checkbox to text input which is next to it.
For example if i check `cb1` then `value=1` 1 should be assigned to `txtcb1`. I need to do this only for checked checkbox only

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="1">  <input class="red" id="txtcb1" type="text" name="fname">
    Name One | Amount <input type="text" name="Amount1" class="auto-sum"> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" value="2"> <input class="red" id="txtcb2" type="text" name="fname"> Name Two | Amount <input type="text" name="Amount2" class="auto-sum"> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" value="3"> <input class="red" id="txtcb3" type="text" name="fname"> Name Three | Amount <input type="text" name="Amount3" class="auto-sum"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" value="4"> <input class="red" id="txtcb4" type="text" name="fname"> Name Four| Amount <input type="text" name="Amount4" class="auto-sum"> <br>
    <br>
    TOTAL  <label id="amountTotal">0 <label>
     AED <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
</form>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJWbNR?editors=1111

Comment: Please post your code on **this site**

Comment: link for code is at bottom

Comment: In my eyes it isn't a good idea to use the event onChange for check- and radioboxes. The event onClick is in my humble opinion the better choice. It works more relyable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**next()**](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the input next to the checkbox like this:

`$(this).next('input[type="text"]').val(id);`

Working snippet below:

```js
function validateForm(myButton) {

  return true;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  $(".auto-sum").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    $(this).keyup(function() {
      calculateSum();
    });
  });

  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var active = $(this).prop('checked');
    if(active){
      $(this).next('input[type="text"]').val(id);
    }else{
      $(this).next('input[type="text"]').val(0);
    }
    $('.auto-sum[name=Amount' + id + ']').attr('disabled', !active);
    calculateSum();
  });

});


function calculateSum() {

  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".auto-sum").each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('disabled')) return;
    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }

  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#amountTotal").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="1">
  <input class="red" id="txtcb1" type="text" name="fname">Name One | Amount
  <input type="text" name="Amount1" class="auto-sum">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" value="2">
  <input class="red" id="txtcb2" type="text" name="fname">Name Two | Amount
  <input type="text" name="Amount2" class="auto-sum">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" value="3">
  <input class="red" id="txtcb3" type="text" name="fname">Name Three | Amount
  <input type="text" name="Amount3" class="auto-sum">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" value="4">
  <input class="red" id="txtcb4" type="text" name="fname">Name Four| Amount
  <input type="text" name="Amount4" class="auto-sum">
  <br>
  <br>TOTAL
  <label id="amountTotal">0
    <label>
      AED
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your checkbox on change event callback, set the id value like below :

```
 $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).next('[type="text"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

[**Updated Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgvgWx?editors=1111)

Comment: Oh. then just use `next` to get the red textbox and assign the value. I've updated my answer. please check the pen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use method `next` inside `change` handler:

```
$(this).next('[type="text"]').val($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `next()`.

```js
function validateForm(myButton){

   return true;
 }

 $(document).ready(function () {

      //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
      //handler to trigger sum event
      $(".auto-sum").each(function () {
          $(this).attr('disabled', true);
          $(this).keyup(function () {
              calculateSum();
          });
      });
   
   $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
       var id = $(this).val();
       var active = this.checked ? this.value : 0;
       var test=$(this).next();
       $(test).val(active);
       $('.auto-sum[name=Amount' + id + ']').attr('disabled', !active);
       calculateSum();
   });

  });

 function calculateSum() {

      var sum = 0;
      //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
      $(".auto-sum").each(function () {
          if ($(this).prop('disabled')) return;
          //add only if the value is number
          if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
              sum += parseFloat(this.value);
          }

      });
      //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
      $("#amountTotal").html(sum.toFixed(2));
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="1">  <input class="red" id="txtcb1" type="text" name="fname">
Name One | Amount <input type="text" name="Amount1" class="auto-sum"> <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb2" value="2"> <input class="red" id="txtcb2" type="text" name="fname"> Name Two | Amount <input type="text" name="Amount2" class="auto-sum"> <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb3" value="3"> <input class="red" id="txtcb3" type="text" name="fname"> Name Three | Amount <input type="text" name="Amount3" class="auto-sum"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb4" value="4"> <input class="red" id="txtcb4" type="text" name="fname"> Name Four| Amount <input type="text" name="Amount4" class="auto-sum"> <br>
 <br>
TOTAL  <label id="amountTotal">0 <label>
 AED <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
  
  </form>
```

Comment: It get same value for all value while it should get value based on checkbox value=1 value=2 .....

Comment: @Learning try now.